# How to print two particular elements in a 2D array

Tags: java, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm attempting to code a basic memory game where the user has to guess two distinct locations on an array of characters to see if both characters match.

Firstly,the user then inputs two coordinate integers Ex: [1,2] and [1,4]. After selecting a size of the puzzle board, my program creates an array of random letters based on the size of the puzzle board.

My problem lies within attempting to print the user's guess coordinates. The first coordinate that is entered always gets printed in the correct index of the array, however the second inputted coordinate is
not accurately displayed.

Here is the segment of code that would print the array, any tips/help would be appreciated thank you.

```
{
    int i=1;

    for (int row=0; row<board.length; row++){
      for (int column=0; column<board[row].length; column++){
        if (x==row && y==column)
              {
          System.out.print (" "+ board[row][column]+ " ");
        }
        else if ( a==row && y==column){
          System.out.print (" "+ board[row][column] + " ");
        }
        else 
          System.out.print (" * " );

      }
      System.out.print (i++);

      System.out.println ();
    }


    int m=1;

    while (m<board.length+1){

      System.out.print (" "+ m++ + " " );

    }
    System.out.println (" ");
  }
```

Comment: Could you show us the complete code?

Comment: Why don't you show the expected output and the output you got? Why do both points have the same `y` coordinate? Is it a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your first entered coordinates are x,y then your second cannot be `a` and `y`.

```
else if ( a==row && y==column){
```

And after reviewing your code the second coordinate was supposed to be a,b

```
else if (a==row && b==column){
```

Or, name them `x2` and `y2` like

```
int x2=keyboard.nextInt( );
x2--;
int y2=keyboard.nextInt( );
y2--;
```

And then

```
else if (x2==row && y2==column){
```

Comment: Ohh I see my error now! Thank you very much. Sometimes it takes a second set of eyes to notice these things. Have a great day.